# How to resolve dependencies in JSR-303 custom validator

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, bean-validation

Suppose that there's a custom validation annotation like this

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {ThirdPartyConstraintValidator.class}) 
@Documented
public @interface ThirdPartyConstraint {
   String message() default "Invalid";

   Class<?>[] groups() default {};

   Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

And corresponding Validator which requires another service

```
public class ThirdPartyConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ThirdPartyConstraint, Pojo> {

  private ThirdPartyService thirdPartyService;

  @Override
  public void initialize(ThirdPartyConstraint thirdPartyConstraint) {}

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(Pojo pojo, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
    return thirdPartyService.isValid(pojo);
  }

  public void setThirdPartyService(ThirdPartyService thirdPartyService) {
    this.thirdPartyService = thirdPartyService;
  }
}
```

The validation context is initialized with Hibernate implementation like this

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

// and then some bean is validated
validator.validate(new Pojo());
```

In the background `validate` method calls `class.newInstance()` to get validator implementations. So, in the case of `ThirdPartyConstraintValidator`, dependency `ThirdPartyService` is never injected.

Is there a way to inject `ThirdPartyService` into `ThirdPartyConstraintValidator` either via setter or constructor when using `ValidationFactory` without any framework?

**UPDATE:**

Following @matthias answer, I updated my `ValidatorFactory` to initialise ThirdPartyConstraintValidator in it

```
public <T extends ConstraintValidator<?, ?>> T getInstance(Class<T> aClass) {
   if (ThirdPartyConstraintValidator.class.equals(aClass)) {
      ThirdPartyConstraintValidator thirdPartyConstraintValidator = new ThirdPartyConstraintValidator();
      thirdPartyConstraintValidator.setThirdPartyService(new ThirdPartyService());
      return (T) thirdPartyConstraintValidator;
   }
   return null;
}
```

Comment: Try add `@Autowired` to `private ThirdPartyService thirdPartyService;`

Comment: @HJz who said that I'm using Spring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a custom ConstraintValidatorFactory to set your dependency.

see [BeanVal Spec](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#constraintsdefinitionimplementation-constraintfactory) or [Hibernate Validator Doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#__code_constraintvalidatorfactory_code)

```
Validator v = Validation.byDefaultProvider().configure()
        .constraintValidatorFactory(new MyConstraintValidatorFactory())
        .buildValidatorFactory()
        .getValidator();

class MyConstraintValidatorFactory implements ConstraintValidatorFactory {

    public <T extends ConstraintValidator<?, ?>> T getInstance(final Class<T> arg0) {
        //do your stuff to set dependencies
        ...
    }

    public void releaseInstance(final ConstraintValidator<?, ?> arg0) {
        ...
    }
}
```